# Classical polarity free magnetic bound state and the quantum hydrogon atom

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, classical-mechanics, quantum-spin

I bumped into a video on Instagram and then tracked to a paper "Polarity Free Magnetic Repulsion and Magnetic Bound State"(https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.07082) by Hamdi Ucar in 2009.

The paper claimed to have obtained "a new mechanism to obtain bound state of entities having magnetic moment" and "can experience a net force in the direction of the weak
field regardless of its position and orientation or can find stable equilibrium with the field itself autonomously", i.e. "Polarity Free Magnetic Bound State".

This immediately reminded me of the hyperfine structure of the hydrogen atom, which resulted from the classical expansion of the relativistic equations.

However, it appeared that the magnetic dipole interaction had already been taken into account for, and what the paper described sounded very similar to the Spin–orbit coupling.

Is it a classical correspondence of the spin orbital coupling, or does it indicate that there might be extra spin spin bounded states in hydrogen atom?